# Testing LMS for SCORM 2004 3rd edition Conformance

Tags: testing, scorm2004

I've installed the SCORM 2004 3rd Edition Test Suite from adlnet.gov and set the java version to 6 update 34 in order to perform the LMS conformance testing, but the test suite is stuck when trying to start ADL LMS Test Content Package API. No error is displayed.

Test Environment Information:
   Operating System: Windows Vista - SP 1
   Java Run-Time Environment: 1.4.2_14

I'm using IE10 with compatibility mode set on IE7 and these are the steps that im going:
- Start the SCORM 2004 3rd Edition Conformance Test Suite Version 1.0.2  ST in new tab next to the LMS tab
- Choose "Learning Management System (LMS) Conformance Test" and than "New LMS Conformance Test"
- Enter the LMS name, version and dev.
- Enter usernames and ids of real users from our LMS that are enrolled as students in previously created course named "SCORM 2004 ADL test course"
- Signed in as the first user I entered in the Test Suite and started the ADL LMS Test Content Package API. 
- The ADL LMS Test Content Package API was launched in the Test Suite. The last message the Test Suite displayed was "Start ADL LMS Test Content Package API".

I have waited for 10 minutes but nothing happened even if I open the course and start clicking on the first chapter. 
Since this scenario didn't work I tried to do the test without prior creating a course. But the result was the same and no course was created (if that was needed).

Note that I'm using the steps described in the readme file provided with the test suite and I've maid all the changes needed in the Java plugin and in the browser.
Also tried in windows XP and 7 with virtualmachine and with live LMS and LMS in my local machine.
The live LMS is hosted on Ubuntu with postgresql and my local is on Windows with mysql.

So I've tried pretty much with everything and I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Does anyone knows how the SCORM 2004 3rd Edition Test Suite works and what am I missing here?
Thank you.